# Perspective / Rotating with css3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a question about rotating and perspective in css3.

I've a div in the middle of the page and on a button on that page, a pagslider toggles up from the left. But, when that pageslider is sliding in, I want my div rotating to the back. I think I've to use Perspective and Rotating for it, but I'm not really sure.

[image: Slider]

I hope you guys understand what I mean. The div has to stay in the visible window. It has to dynamically go in depth, and on closing the pageslider it has to go fullscreen again.